# Creating Variable Variables from MySQL Values

Tags: php, variable-variables

Is it possible to create a dynamic variable in PHP based on the value that comes from mysql database?

I mean,

say I have a field in mysql `State`

When I read the value in php using `row['State']` from the database and if I get a value like `Alabama`, I want to have a variable created like `$Alabama_count` and I will initialize to `0` or `1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$varname = $row['State'] . '_count';
$$varname = 0; // or 1
```

Answer (score 3):

There does exist an easier solution. Instead of creating something called $Alabama_count, you could create this very easily: `$count['Alabama']`, i.e. `$count[$row['State']]`.

Comment: I've never thought of a good place to use variable variables where an associative array wouldn't be better. Though you do need to say: $count[$row['State']]
(missing $ on row)

Comment: @Johnr: yep, I agree. Thanks for the note. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `${$row['State']}` if `$row['State']` is `Alabama` it's the same as doing `$Alabama`.

Similarly you can do the same to `_count`:

```
${$row['State'] . '_count'} = 0; // $Alabama_count = 0;
${$row['State'] . '_count'}++; // $Alabama_count++; // $Alabama_count = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use variable variables, something like this?

```
$var_name = "{$row['State']}_count";
$$var_name = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this variables of variables using $ symbol twice: for example:

```
$variable = 'Some_text';
$$name = 123;
echo $Some_text;
//this will output 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you want but take a look at [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) on the php manual

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable named ${$row['State'].'_count'} and set its value. I'm not sure how advisable this would be, however. You don't know what variables you will be left with.